# Merchant-Initiated transaction using Apple Pay / Google Pay cards (by Stripe integration)

Tags: mobile, stripe-payments, payment, applepay, google-pay

I would like to implement Stripe payments in mobile app. The model we would like to have is:

1. the user saves the payment card when registering for the application. 3ds authorisation follows
2. if the user breaks the rules of the app, the card is charged (Merchant-Initiated transaction)

Stripe allows this model, called `Save and reuse` - [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?). They also mention, that Apple Pay and Google Pay can be used in that model ([link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#apple-pay-and-google-pay)). The question is, how does it work in practice? One consultant mentioned that we may encounter many bugs when using such a model with Apple Pay / Google Pay. One of the reply:

> As an extra mile, I can tell you that to prevent the issue, you have
> to be ready for authentications, and preferably charge via payment
> links or one off invoices in the case of one off payments that would
> use apple pay or google pay.
>
> Which means that you need to be in session, since it would be the best
> option in all cases, although this doesn't necessarily mean you can
> not use and reuse cards, you probably can but you may find bugs.

Does anyone have any experience with that? Can we really have problems charging cards added by Apple Pay / Google Pay in the way I have described above?

Comment: I'm not sure where your quote comes from but I'm pretty sure it's not an official statement from Stripe and it isn't really accurate. Any card payment or Google/Apple Pay may be subject to 3DS auth which requires getting the customer back on-session and using [confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-existing) to handle 3DS.

Comment: My quote comes from support-reply@stripe.com email :)
I know, that the card payment may requires 3DS auth, but my question is more about whether 3ds will be more problematic for google/apple pay than for regular cards. The 3DS has many exemptions and our case is one of them.